# How to specify an empty element in YAML for Log4J 2 "OnStartupTriggeringPolicy"

Tags: yaml, log4j2

How do I give any empty element in YAML?

I'm configuring lo4j2 triggers with "OnStartupTriggerPolicy".

```
 <Policies>
       <OnStartupTriggeringPolicy />
 </Policies>
```

Log4J is not accepting this.

```
 Policies:
        OnStartupTriggeringPolicy:
        SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy:
           size: "20 MB"
```

ERROR Policies contains an invalid element or attribute "OnStartupTriggeringPolicy"

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
OnStartupTriggeringPolicy: {}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding *why* and/or *how* this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score 1):

If you leave a value empty YAML assumes the `null` value. Which is not the same as having no value. You should specify the empty string:

```
Policies:
  OnStartupTriggeringPolicy: ""
  SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy:
    size: "20 MB"
```

Comment: YAML is accepting it but, Log4j 2 keeps complaining.
2015-08-25 14:05:43,033 ERROR Policies contains an invalid element or attribute "OnStartupTriggeringPolicy"

Answer (score 0):

However we can define empty element by putting opening and closing curly bracket like this -

```
OnStartupTriggeringPolicy: {}
TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy: {}
```

But it is better to specify the attribute of this elements. OnStartupTriggeringPolicy has a attribute name "minSize", this calculate the minimium size of file on startup and if satisfy then it create a new rollover file -

```
OnStartupTriggeringPolicy:
        minSize: 5120 // this is long value of file size
```

Similarly for TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy -

```
TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy:
        interval: 1
        modulate: true
        maxRandomDelay: 0
```